# This error kept came when i test yolov3 [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Models/yolo-tiny-onecls/yolov3-tiny-onecls.cfg'

Tags: python, yolo

I was testing [this code](https://github.com/GajuuzZ/Human-Falling-Detect-Tracks/blob/master/Data/create_dataset_2.py) on my computer through colab, but it keeps showing error message:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Models/yolo-tiny-onecls/yolov3-tiny-onecls.cfg'.

I wonder if it is because the path problem, but I don't know how to fix it and it already bother me for weeks.
Any one can help please .

[image]

Comment: is your python file in the same directory as Models folder?

Comment: yes, i put the colab notebook under the "Models" folder but it still doesn't work...

Comment: try os.listdir() . what do you get? also try giving absolute path starting from /content

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean, I get the following files

['fn.py',
 'PoseEstimateLoader.py',
 'App.py',
 'CameraLoader.py',
 'main.py',
 'pPose_nms.py',
 'pose_utils.py',
 'ActionsEstLoader.py',
 'sample1.gif',
 'DetectorLoader.py',
 'README.md',
 'Models',
 'Actionsrecognition',
 'Data',
 'Track',
 'Detection',
 'SPPE',
 '__pycache__']

and I also change the path into absolute path, but it still shows the same error message.

Comment: path is case sensitive. also try adding ./ atthe start if starting with models and / at the start  if starting with content

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I will try it!

Answer (score 0):

YOU can download it from here [link](http://li1421-74.members.linode.com/lior2/Human-Falling-Detect-Tracks/-/tree/781fd62504849960d1acf35e36e2fa87ab31ad90/Models/yolo-tiny-onecls)  :
after that put it in the path and I think it will solve the problem